# Random select record with percent on specific column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am selecting random distinct data from a table and it is working fine. The data also has a city column. I want to select a random record with respect to the percent of specific city. Like I want top 100 random records from a table but it should be 20% of New York, 50% of Texas and 30% of Vegas. Need suggestions how to do this in this query

```
select distinct top 10 
    c.Phone, NEWID() as ArrangeOrder,
    max(c.city) as 'City', max(c.id),
    max(c.province) as 'Province', max(c.MediaSourceType), 
    max(c.[PrimarySelfie])  
from 
    Contestants c (nolock) 
inner join
    SocialMediaHashTags st  (nolock) on c.id = st.contestantid where st.contenttype = 1 
                                     and c.IsWinner = 0 
                                     and st.PostDate >= '04-25-2017 00:00:00' 
                                     and st.PostDate <= '04-25-2017 23:59:59' 
                                     and c.city is not null 
                                     and c.Province is not null 
                                     and c.CityId is not null 
                                     and c.CityId > 0
group by 
    c.Phone
order by 
    NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it's dificult to understand what you're doing,

But, if you just want quotas on your request, you could make 3 different requests, one for each quota, and limit the number of answers.

Please, give way more details of what you're doing, like if you're using php or only sql requests etc...

Comment: what i am trying to do is to get random top records from a tables but with some percent values that i will provide like this query i provided above is returning me top distinct records from table but now i want to return record by specific percent like 10% of newyork 20% of texas etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how the query relates to the question.  If you have data with a column for city -- along with values such as "Vegas" and "Texas" -- you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by city order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where (t.city = 'NewYork' and seqnum <= 20) or
      (t.city = 'Texas' and seqnum <= 50) or
      (t.city = 'Vegas' and seqnum <= 30);
```

Comment: with this query i provided above i am getting random top 10 records from the table

Comment: The query in this answer would return 100 records.